# How to update values in a for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a for-loop that initializes 3 vectors (launch_2012, amount, and one_week_bf) and creates a data frame.  Then, it predicts a single week's of data and inserts it into vectors (amount and one_week_bf), and recreates the data.frame again; this process is looped 8 times.  However, I can't seem to get the data.frame to update the new amounts.  Would anyone be able to assist please?

```
for (i in 1:8) {
    launch_2012 <- c(rep('bf', 5), 'launch', rep('af', 7))
    amount <- c(7946, 6641, 5975, 5378, 5217, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
    one_week_bf <- c(NA, 7946, 6641, 5975, 5378, 5217, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
    newdata <- data.frame(amount = amount, one_week_bf = one_week_bf, launch = launch_2012, week = week)
    predicted <- predict(model0a, newdata)
    amount[i+5] <- predicted[i+5]
    one_week_bf[i+6] <- predicted[i+5]
    View(newdata)
}
```

Comment: Get them initial vectors outta that for loop! (Putting them in resets/overwrites the values each time.)

Comment: thanks for the guidance!  yea that was the problem.  Would you know how I could also edit the function so it returns a dataframe in the global environment which I can use to plot?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is `model0a`? I've downvoted this as your example is not reproducible or is unclear. Happy to help though (and upvote if you put effort into improving this question).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure since your example is not reproducible, but note that `predict.lm(...)` by default has `na.action=na.pass`, which means that any rows in `newdata` that have *any NA values* by default generate `NA` for the prediction. Since your first pass of `newdata` has `NA` in rows 6-13, `predicted` will have `NA` in those same elements. This means that `amounts` and `one_week_bf` will have `NA` in those elements, which in turn will generate the same `newdata` each time.

Answer (score 0):

None of this should be in a for loop.

```
x <- data.frame("launch_2012" = c(rep('bf', 5), 'launch', rep('af', 7)),
                "amount"=c(7946, 6641, 5975, 5378, 5217, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                "one_week_bf"=c(NA, 7946, 6641, 5975, 5378, 5217, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
x$new_amount <- #the replacement from your predict vector
x$new_one_week_bf <- #the replacement from your predict vector
```

Note I have no idea what model0a does, so just gave what the new columns should be as whatever the resulting vector is from your predict function. This will add the new data as new columns